# Static linking - working with GTKmm application? - revised

Tags: c++, linux, gtk, static-linking, gtkmm

Is it possible to make a static linking (compilation) on Gtk(mm) program? I need the program to be less relaying on dependences in user's system.

I try:

```
g++ -static data/Area.h data/Picture.cpp data/GLScene.cpp data/KBDialog.cpp data/Dialogs.h data/FilePreview.cpp data/MainWindow.cpp prog.cpp -o prog `pkg-config --cflags --libs  gtkmm-2.4 gtkglextmm-1.2 exiv2`
```

but It fails:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtkmm-2.4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latkmm-1.6
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdkmm-2.4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangomm-1.4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgio-2.0.a(glocalfileinfo.o): In function `lookup_gid_name':
(.text+0x207a): warning: Using 'getgrgid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgio-2.0.a(glocalvfs.o): In function `g_local_vfs_parse_name':
(.text+0x26c): warning: Using 'getpwnam' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libglib-2.0.a(gutils.o): In function `g_get_any_init_do':
(.text+0x1244): warning: Using 'getpwuid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libglib-2.0.a(gutils.o): In function `g_get_any_init_do':
(.text+0x1237): warning: Using 'setpwent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libglib-2.0.a(gutils.o): In function `g_get_any_init_do':
(.text+0x124f): warning: Using 'endpwent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libglib-2.0.a(gutils.o): In function `g_get_any_init_do':
(.text+0xf6e): warning: Using 'getpwnam_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgio-2.0.a(glocalfileinfo.o): In function `lookup_uid_data':
(.text+0x1eea): warning: Using 'getpwuid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libX11.a(xim_trans.o): In function `_XimXTransSocketUNIXConnect':
(.text+0xe23): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgio-2.0.a(gnetworkaddress.o): In function `g_network_address_parse':
(.text+0xe3c): warning: Using 'getservbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/libgio-2.0.a(gnetworkaddress.o): In function `g_network_address_parse':
(.text+0xe4c): warning: Using 'endservent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: *<bickering and name-calling removed>* Alright enough with the raging, let's see what we can pick out of this output.

Comment: I added another long new reply.

Comment: You really should have given much more context in your very first question.......

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would rather avoid doing that, because GTK depends on tricky low level libraries which are really very system specific (perhaps `libfontconfig.so` etc), and contains system-specific information (e.g. builtin paths for fonts...).

I also think that GTK needs dynamic shared libraries to implement theming or styling (so GTK itself is calling `dlopen`, and having a *statically linked*  `libdl` is not reasonable).

I suggest at least linking dynamically gtk and all its dependencies.

Comment: I just need to do static-linking for gtkglextmm. Any ideas?

Comment: You could link statically only one single library, e.g. `gcc foo.o -Bstatic -lgtkglextmm -Bdynamic -lgtk ...`

Comment: But don't do that, even for a single library. See my answer below

Comment: I tried that, but still I receive first 6 lines of errors listed in the first post.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, please do not post these types of answers. This is not an answer. It's you disagree with his question, which is a waste of everyone's time who comes to this page. If you don't have an answer to a question, move on. Don't tell the author they're wrong for what they want to do. You do not know their reasons, and they may not wish to tell you what they are. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

(Your question asked twice pisses me off, so here is a more detailed answer that I might edit and complete further)

---

**Why dynamically linked shared libraries are useful?**

First, **almost every binary is dynamically linked** on today's Linux systems. On my Debian/Sid system, I only have `/sbin/ldconfig` `/bin/sash` and `/usr/bin/rar` statically linked executables, but about seven thousand other dynamically linked executables (under `/bin` & `/usr/bin`). Even essential programs like `/sbin/init` are today dynamically linked.

There are several wins in having mostly dynamically linked ELF executables using [shared libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_library#Shared_libraries)

1. **Avoid wasting disk space**. When dynamically linked executables did not exist (1986 era, SunOS3.5, because the kernel was not able to [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) file segments), people took a lot of time mixing several binaries in a single one (I remember `textedit` and `cmdtool` being the same binary, a mix of several programs on SunOS3.5) to win disk space. Ok, disk space is cheaper today, but if my seven thousand programs each had to link statically `libc` that would consume several gigabytes of disk space (and that would mean an extra DVD or hours of networking upload when installing a Linux distribution).
2. **Enabling an easier update**. When the packaging system (`apt-get`, `dpkg` and friends on Debian) upgrades a common shared library (like the GLibC or Gtk), it replaces the dynamically linked shared libraries (`*.so` files, called [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELF) shared objects) and all the future executions of binary using them take profit. So if `/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so` is updated, there is no need to update `/usr/bin/gedit` to take advantage of the bug fixes inside `libgtk-3.so`; just restarting `gedit` will make it profit of improvements in `libgtk-3.so`
3. **More efficient overall RAM usage**. A file like `libc.so` is used by almost every process, and even `libgtk-3.so` is used by dozens of processes. Most of it is `mmap`-ed read-only "text" segment (notably containing the executable binary machine code and read-only constants like string); this mapping is using the same RAM cells for every process using it. So the memory is shared
4. **Legal compliance with LGPL license** 
   The [LGPL-2.1](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html) license of GTK libraries is the only reason why you are legally allowed to use GTK (i.e. run GTK programs, and link your own program with GTK). This license gives you rights, in particular the one to improve GTK or take advantage of GTK improvements, but you should not prohibit users of your (e.g. proprietary) program linking `/usr/lib/gtk-3.so` to take advantage of improvements inside GTK itself. The section 6 of LGPL2.1 mention explicitly dynamic linking. **You are not allowed to distribute statically linked GTK binaries** without giving the user the mean to upgrade his GTK library. The most convenient way is having your GTK program dynamically linked against `libgtk-3.so`. A less easy alternative would be to distribute your statically linked executable with its object `*.o` files and instructions on how to re-link it statically against an hypothetical improved `libgtk.a` (which don't exist).
5. **Plugin ability to dynamically load other library modules**
   A program can load some shared object at run time using the [dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) function (based upon the `mmap` system call, thru the `-ldl` library). This is how plugins are possible on Linux. GTK uses itself very actively this ability: theming, styling, and perhaps fonts are using `dlopen` and implemented by `dlopen`-ing appropriate stuff. Since `dlopen` is a public interface to the dynamic loader `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, the `-ldl` library is a dynamically shared object  `libdl.so.2` sharing functionality and code with the dynamic loader (itself referenced in every dynamically linked executable as the "ELF interpreter"). It is uncommon and unwise to link `-ldl` statically. Even the `libc.so` library may load other modules (perhaps for DNS support, etc...); some functionalities are restricted in statically linked executables (see file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` etc.).
6. dynamic linking is slightly slower at startup time, since a program has to initiate and dynamically load (this is the role of `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`) at startup all the dynamic libraries it needs. Code inside a dynamic library needs to be [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) otherwise the relocation part of dynamically loaded libraries would be too big (and the relocation effort at start-up too long), which may cost an extra register (and this is mostly true on 32 bits x86 processors, much less on x86-64 or AMD64 64 bits ones) so makes up slightly bigger machine code (on 32 bits x86 machines, we are speaking of a few percents of size increase and runtime slowdown; on 64 bits machines, it is negligible). Of course, relocating hundred of thousands of external calls may take some time (and happens more with C++ code than with C code, perhaps because of name mangling issues).

---

**Why you** (Marco) **should not statically link your GTK binary**?

The five first points above should convince you that linking statically GTK is an evil thing to do. In particular, take attention of the legal aspects (LGPL): making knowingly an LGPL violation is a huge professional mistake, don't do that.

If you really wanted, with weeks of effort, you probably could be technically able (by recompiling and hacking GTK source code) to link statically your binary with GTK (with some reduced functionalities, like no theming), but that is probably **unethical** and useless. If your boss is stupid enough to require you that, try to convince him (or else find another job). And the very fact that you've asked on a public forum how to link statically GTK (which I am understanding as "*how to violate the LGPL license*") put you at risk. There are organizations -like [gpl-violations](http://gpl-violations.org/)- which take attention to that.

I don't see any useful reason to statically link a GTK program. Even proprietary programs using a GUI library are dynamically linked (a good example is AMD FGLRX driver and its companion programs like `amdccle` providing a Qt based graphical interface for installation).

Of course, you may want to deal with dependencies. Leave that to the package manager of your linux distribution.

If you want more help, please explain much more what you really want to do, and convince us that you don't ask help in violating a license. Better yet, try to distribute your software with a free license like e.g. [GPLv3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/#GPL)

Comment: Brilliant!!... Covered so many aspects including the license!

Comment: I appreciate your effort in posting this long answer. I wanted to do static-linking because my program uses gtkglextmm library and on my promoter's PC there is no such library (I write BA thesis). He uses some old Ubuntu version and sadly the Packet Manager can't install that library on his system (it just doesn't find it). So he advised me do to static-linking of gtkglextmm and give him back my application. Do you have any advice for me? :(

Comment: Just link statically one library, as I suggested in a comment to my first reply.

Comment: remove the `-static`;  Run `pkg-config --cflags --libs  gtkmm-2.4 gtkglextmm-1.2 exiv2` in a terminal. Replace the `-lgdkglextmm-x11-1.2` with `-Bstatic -lgdkglextmm-x11-1.2 -Bdynamic`. Put that replaced string in your `Makefile`. Then help your promoter to upgrade his Ubuntu on his machine.

Comment: Shouldn't I do: -Wl,-Bstatic -lgdkglextmm-x11-1.2 -Wl,-Bdynamic instead?

Comment: Yeah, I really like your answer, no bias at all. You don't want to even mention single benefit of static linking. Like, for instance, constant behaviour of code, no need to deal with dependencies, and no breakages that might be introduced in different mixes of shared objects. Good luck fixing every single bug that arises because different sets of shared objects were used in different environments.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, please do not post these types of answers.   This is not an answer.  It's you disagree with his question, which is a waste of everyone's time who comes to this page.   If you don't have an answer to a question, move on.   Don't tell the author they're wrong for what they want to do.  You do not know their  reasons, and they may not wish to tell you what they are.  

Thank you.