How can I link against a static library that depends on other libraries in cmake?
I have a static library that depends on gtkmm. I'm creating a liblibrary.a file successfully, however when I try to link a client app against this library, I get undefined reference to gtkmm's functions. How can I link against a static library that depends on other libraries?
Library's cmake file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(library)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM REQUIRED gtkmm-3.0)
include_directories(${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS})


add_library(library STATIC library.cpp library.h)

target_link_libraries(library ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES})

Client app's cmake file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(cairomotion)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

include_directories(/home/user/Projects/library)

add_executable(client main.cpp)


target_link_libraries(client /home/user/Projects/library/cmake-build-debug/liblibrary.a)


Thank you for your help

target_link_libraries(library PUBLIC ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES})/target_link_libraries(client library)?

@Jarod42, I changed to target_link_libraries(library PUBLIC ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES}), unfortunately no result. About target_link_libraries(client library), the static library is not installed system wide, so I have to use the absolute path.

Sorry, I found that statically linking gtkmm is not recommended...  so the question does not worth answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229094/static-linking-working-with-gtkmm-application-revised

"the static library is not installed system wide", You generally then have it in your CMakelist as include(library), and so, using target would do the jobs (using INTERFACE CMake stuff, as using PUBLIC to "inherits" some "automatic" link/include/defines).

If you're going to separate your library and client into two projects, you must export your library from its build. Here is a heavily commented example:
Library
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

## Declare the project and its version.
# A version number is essential for find_package to work
# correctly. Set the major version to zero until you have
# defined a stable API/ABI.
project(library VERSION 0.1.0)

## Find our dependencies.
# We ask PkgConfig to create an imported target because
# one should ALWAYS link to a target rather than to a
# raw library by path. Linking to a target also sets up
# include directories
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(gtkmm-3.0 REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET gtkmm-3.0)

## Create our main library target.
# We also create an alias that will match its exported
# name in case we want to support add_subdirectory or
# FetchContent down the line. The installation rules
# below would need to be guarded by an off-by-default
# option() and components would need to be added.
add_library(library STATIC library.cpp)
add_library(library::library ALIAS library)

## Declare the public headers.
# These headers will be installed along with the binaries.
# Additionally, targets linking to this library will have
# their include paths set appropriately.
target_sources(library PUBLIC FILE_SET HEADERS FILES library.h)

## Set the language level.
# Declaring this as a public build requirement of the
# library will ensure that other targets that link to
# it will also require C++23.
target_compile_features(library PUBLIC cxx_std_23)

## Link our dependencies.
# This is the way to link libraries. With this, we have
# completed the process of defining our library and its
# usage requirements.
target_link_libraries(library PRIVATE PkgConfig::gtkmm-3.0)

## Import the build-in helpers for defining install rules
include(GNUInstallDirs)
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

## Create a custom path variable for the location of the
# CMake package files.
set(library_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/library"
    CACHE STRING "Path to CMake config files")

## Create the package config file.
configure_package_config_file(
  "library-config.cmake.in" "${library_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR}/library-config.cmake"
  INSTALL_DESTINATION "${library_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR}")

## Create the package version file.
write_basic_package_version_file(
  "${library_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR}/library-config-version.cmake"
  COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion
)

## Install the package config/version files.
install(FILES
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${library_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR}/library-config.cmake"
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${library_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR}/library-config-version.cmake"
        DESTINATION "${library_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR}")

## Install the library
install(TARGETS library
        EXPORT library-targets
        FILE_SET HEADERS)

## Generate a file that contains the target definition
# for the library.
install(EXPORT library-targets
        DESTINATION "${library_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR}"
        NAMESPACE library::)

library-config.cmake.in
@PACKAGE_INIT@

## We use find_dependency rather than find_package
# inside a package config file.
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)

## Look for gtkmm-3.0 in the downstream build
find_dependency(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(gtkmm-3.0 IMPORTED_TARGET gtkmm-3.0)

## Provide a helpful error message if we cannot find it
# It is not appropriate to FATAL_ERROR for this since the
# downstream user should decide what to do if your package
# cannot be found.
if (NOT gtkmm-3.0_FOUND)
    set(${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME}_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE
        "dependency gtkmm-3.0 could not be found")
    set(${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME}_FOUND 0)
    return()
endif ()

## Add the generated targets
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/library-targets.cmake")

## Ensure that no invalid components were requested
check_required_components(${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME})

Client
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(cairomotion)

## Find the library
find_package(library REQUIRED)

## Create the client executable
add_executable(client main.cpp)
target_compile_features(client PRIVATE cxx_std_23)

## Link to the library
target_link_libraries(client PRIVATE library::library)

Build steps:
Assuming you have both project directories in ~/workspace:
~/workspace$ ls
client  library
~/workspace$ export CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
~/workspace$ export CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja
~/workspace$ export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="$PWD/.local"
~/workspace$ cmake -S library -B library/build
~/workspace$ cmake --build library/build
~/workspace$ cmake --install library/build --prefix "$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH"
~/workspace$ cmake -S client -B client/build
~/workspace$ cmake --build client/build

Setting CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH here provides the glue between the two projects.

Sorry, I found that statically linking gtkmm is not recommended...
Static linking - working with GTKmm application? - revised
This CMakeLists.txt works:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(cairomotion)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

include_directories(/home/user/Projects/library)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM REQUIRED gtkmm-3.0)
include_directories(${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(client main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(client /home/user/Projects/library/cmake-build-debug/liblibrary.a ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES})


Putting an absolute path to a library in target_link_libraries is wrong 100% of the time. Do not do this.
